# Как не показывать миниатюру wp если физически нет файла?

Tags: wordpress

Такая вот проблема, у нас миниатюры записи удаляются через 6 месяцев просто из папки uploads, но не через админку, т.е. в админке висит типо есть миниатюра, а физически файла нет. Как мне если файла нет физически, то показывать другую картинку? даже мыслей нет как это сделать. Капните пожалуйста, я предлагал написать какой то скрипт который бы с записи удалял саму миниатюру, но сказали так не пойдет. Укажите куда копать

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё просто, надо добавить атрибут onError в img

```
onError="this.src='datas/img/none.png'"
```